# Nightmare: Calling evaluate a dynamic number of times to scrape a dynamically paginated site

Tags: javascript, node.js, nightmare

I'm scrapping a dynamically paginated website, the pages are loaded using js and are not accessible via the url.

I need to extract info from each page, print it to stdout, go to the next page and repeat the process.

To load the pages there's an expensive setup process.

The easiest way of doing it without repeating the setup, would be to have a recursive function as the run callback, that checks if there's a next page and if it doesn't ends the process.

Something like this:

```
function extractInfoAndGoToNextPage(err, nightmareInstance){

    function isThereNextPage(result){
        if(!result) process.end()
    }

    nightmareInstance.evaluate(extractInfo, printInfo)
    .exists(nextPageSelector, isThereNextPage)
    .click(nextPageSelector)
    .wait()
    .run(extractInfoAndGoToNextPage)
}


new Nightmare().goto(website)
...setup process...
.run(extractInfoAndGoToNextPage)
```

The problem is that after the run the instance seems to loose state.

How can I extract the information one page at the time without needing to set up the instance for each page?

Comment: If you are injecting js as part of your page setup process and url changes then you need to do setup again. If URL remains same then you should be able to use page setup multiple times.